# Giving human readable names to servers in jobrunr

Tags: jobrunr

Jobrunr dashboard by default shows UUIDs in place of server names.

Is it possible to make this more human readable and/or customizable? For example, ip address, hostname etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this is not possible, but feel free to create an feature request or (even better) a PR to add this functionality.

**Update on 17/01/2023:** this is now solved in JobRunr v6. Not only the background job servers will show the names but also inside the processing block a job.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try in a PR, could you give me some starting points?